Issues with "Sentinel RMS License Server" connections through wireguard?
I do have several clients at one site and an application with a "Sentinel RMS License Server" on the server side. Sentinel uses TCP port 5093.
If I setup an IPSec connection between the two sites, the connection works fine between client and license server. The firewall is either passing all through, or I setup rules with only tcp/5093 open.
If I setup a wireguard based network (netbird.io), between the same sites, also with no policy restrictions, ping and other TCP connections work just fine. However, the client cannot connect the Sentinel License server at all.
Anyone has similar experiences? Perhaps there is a hint on how to fix this?

So far, I did not find a solution. But I did find the reason it does not work.
